# Webpack execute task after all configurations are done or before all

Tags: javascript, webpack

Webpack has some nice hooks to execute tasks before a compilation starts or after all is done. But these hooks are not working with multi-configuration setups (returning an array of webpack-configuration objects).
In these setups you or the plugin you are using registers the desired hook on one specific configurations and thus the hook will be executed dependent on the life cycle of this specific configuration. E.g., the onDone hook gets fired if the configuration it is registered to is done and not if all configurations are done.

How to register hooks that are executed before all or after all webpacktask are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are no such hooks provided by webpack directly.
There is a pending feature request: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7613

But for now there is a little workaround using the dependency feature. The idea is to create an additional empty webpack configuration that is the predecessor or the successor of all other configuration. The desired hook will than be registered to this new configurations:

I'am using webpack 5.

Given webpack.A.js

```
export default {
  name: "A",
  dependencies: ["Before"],
  // ...
}
```

Given webpack.B.js

```
export default {
  name: "B",
  dependencies: ["Before"],
  // ...
}
```

It is important to give all configurations objects a name

webpack.all.json

```
import A from "./webpack.A.js"
import B from "./webpack.B.js"

const beforeConfig = {
    name: "Before",
    mode: "development",
    entry: {}, // must be an empty object
    plugins: [...],
}

const afterConfig = {
    name: "After",
    mode: "development",
    entry: {}, // must be an empty object
    plugins: [...],
    dependencies: ["A", "B"]
}

default export [beforeConfig, A, B, afterConfig]
```

The beforeConfig is the predecessor for all other configuration, which is why its hooks will be executed before all.
The afterConfig is the successor of all other configurations, which is why its oneDone hook will only be executed if all is done.

I hope this helps others having the same problem.